# android scrollview in listview

Tags: android, listview, scrollview

hi i have a custom listview , each contain a bulk text ,i given the text in scroll view ,my problem am not able to scroll items in listview , when i press the text actually listview is scrolling, but in some case it work fine

Comment: Did you override scroll idle methods, just override it and use log statements, there and check whether you got the log messages in your logcat, when you finished scrolling

Comment: @Michel Geoffroy i have set the click listener for scrollview but it's not listen

Answer (score 0):

ScrollView and any other view that natively supports scrolling, i.e. ListView, do not play nice together.

Answer (score 0):

The only way you can have ScrollView and ListView together is when the ScrollView scrolls horizontally and the ListView (obviously) is scrolling vertically. Check out the Google I/O talk on ListView.

The Google I/O talk - http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=wDBM6wVEO70

Comment: you can send the link of this Google IO please :)

Comment: Added the link to the answer.